# preg match question

Tags: php, regex, match

I hate regular expressions, but for what I am doing I'm sure there is no other simpler option.
Anyway I have been working with this experssion:

```
/(([a-zA-z_]+)[\.]?+)+/
```

To try and match something similar to this

```
"text.lol".something.another etc..
```

And with preg_match return an array similar to

```
Array
(
    [0] => "text.lol"
    [1] => something
    [2] => another
)
```

But instead all I am getting is the first matched item twice in the array?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your intent to explode the string using periods as a delimiter, while ignoring periods within double quotes?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your input?

Comment: also in future I would like to implement ignoring periods in brackets, square brackets and curly braces

Comment: real world examples are easier to work with, well at least for me

Comment: @tokam my input is `"text.lol".something.another etc..`. This is in the question

Comment: Can an item contain quotes? Like `"blue \"teeth\""."text.lol".etc`

Comment: preferably if the item is in quotes it should be able to contain anything.

Comment: Please check my edited answer for a more complete implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives the output you want for the input you specified:

```
$s = '"text.lol".something.another';
preg_match_all('/"[^"]+"|[^.]+/', $s, $m);
$values = $m[0];
print_r($values);
```

Here's a full implementation that allows escaped quotes:

```
function encode($original) {
    foreach ($original as &$s) {
        $s = addslashes($s);
        if (strpos($s, '.') !== false) $s = '"'.$s.'"';
    }
    return join('.', $original);
}

function decode($s) {
    // These regular expressions courtesy of ridgerunner:
    preg_match_all('/"([^"\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"|([^.]+)/', $s, $m);
    // This one has poorer performance, but is easier to read:
    // preg_match_all('/"((?:\\\\.|[^"\\\\])+)"|([^.]+)/', $s, $m);
    $values = array();
    foreach ($m[1] as $k => $v) $values[] = stripslashes($v? $v : $m[2][$k]);
    return $values;
}

$test_cases = array('a.b', 'a\\', '.a\\', 'a.b"c', '"a');
$encoded = encode($test_cases);
$decoded = decode($encoded);

echo '<pre>Encoded: '.$encoded."\n";
echo print_r($decoded, 1).'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Encoded: "a.b".a\\.".a\\"."a.b\"c".\"a
Array
(
    [0] => a.b
    [1] => a\
    [2] => .a\
    [3] => a.b"c
    [4] => "a
)
```

Comment: That's brilliant. I tried to do what you did with [^"] with a negative look behind assertion lol

Comment: @tokam Nice :-) I briefly thought I needed a look-behind.... Regular expressions are so much fun; it's sad to see so many people hate them.

Comment: I don't believe a regex implementation is required to give precedence to the left side of the `|` over the right side like that when they both match.  It's probably a fairly safe bet it won't change, but there's a chance a future optimization in the php library could leave it a very difficult bug to track down.  Adding a `"` inside the brackets on the right hand side would be superfluous for this implementation, but more portable and safer in the long run.

Comment: I had two regexes one matching the "abc.akc" case and one for the other, but I had problems connecting both with a non capturing group. I think mostly when using preg_match it is better to use as less groups as possible. I liked the regex of you! 



One case: (?<=\")(.+?)\"\\.)
The other: (?<!\")(.+?)\\. 
xD

Edit: I support so much on so but nobody votes me up. 40 question answered in 3 days :(

Comment: @Karl, can you post the full modified regex? I'm not sure exactly what you are suggesting. I'd like to update my answer if there's a simple way to future-proof it. @tokam - sadness.

Comment: @Karl, according to http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt, "alternative branches are tried from left to right". As long as we use PCRE functions, it seems that PHP's implementation should work that way.

Comment: @Mark - Part 1: your solution is close, but the expression used to match double quoted strings has a weakness: It does not correctly handle escaped escapes! If we add an escaped-escape to the end of the first quoted string (which requires _four_ slashes) like so: `'"text.lol\\\\"'` it fails and the resulting array is all messed up. This can be easily fixed by changing this subexpression: `'"((?:\\\\"|[^"])+)"'` to this: `'"((?:\\\\.|[^"\\\\])+)"'`.

Comment: @Mark - Part 2: Or better yet apply Friedl's "[Unrolling the loop](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "See: Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition) By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!")" efficiency technique to get this: `'"([^"\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"'`. Its a bit longer but is much faster.

Comment: @ridgerunner, thanks for the help! I've edited my answer to include your regular expressions.